# Use a program that validates dates with bool c++?

Tags: c++, boolean, codeblocks

I am new to C++ programming and haven't done anything with booleans. What ara the mistakes that I am doing in this program? Thanks in advance!

```
//INPUT: Enter a date in the format DDMMYYYY, for example 14102014
//OUTPUT: Says if the date is correct or no
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    bool incorrecta;
    cout << "ENTER A DATE:" << endl;
    int data;
    cin>> data;

    int any= data%10000;
    int dmes= data/10000;
    int dia= dmes/100;
    int mes= dmes%100;


    if (mes>12 or mes<1) incorrecta=true;
    else if (any>3399 or any<100) incorrecta=true;
    else if ((dia<1 or dia>31) and (mes==1 or mes==5 or mes==3 or mes==7 or mes==8 or mes==10 or mes==12)) incorrecta=true;
    else if ((dia<1 or dia>30) and (mes==4 or mes==6 or mes==9 or mes==11)) cout<< "THE DATE IS INCORRECT"<< endl;
    else if (mes==2){
        if(any%4==0 and (any%100!=0 or any%400==0)) cout <<"THE DATE IS CORRECT" <<endl;
        else incorrecta=true;
        }


    if (incorrecta==true) cout<< "THE DATE IS INCORRECT"<< endl;
    else  cout <<"THE DATE IS CORRECT" <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What should the program do? What is the program doing? Can you reduce the code so that we only have to watch the lines which can possibly wrong? Is it also possible to get it in English? Your print outs are not helpful for the people here. Got you an compiler error, a runtime error or simply wrong logic. Sorry, my crystal ball is broken :-)

Comment: Yeah, so what's your problem?

Comment: Replace the first `cout<< "LA DATA ES INCORRECTA"<< endl` with `incorrecta = true` and the first `cout <<"LA DATA ES CORRECTA" <<endl` with `incorrecta = false`. In other words: *first* determine the result, *then* output your message about the result (this is a generally useful principle).

Comment: Sorry, I have translate the couts in English,  it's simply wrong logic, the program always says "THE DATE IS INCORRECT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe all you need is to put `incorrecta=false;` before the first `if` so the variable is initialized correctly. It will then still be false at the end if none of the conditions are met.

Comment: Thank you!! the mistake was what you have said. Now the program works perfect:)